# What benefits or disadvantages would importing a module that contains 'import' commands?

Tags: python

If I were to create a module that was called for example `imp_mod.py` and inside it contained all (subjectively used) relevant modules that I frequently used.

Would importing this module into my main program allow me access to the imports contained inside `imp_mod.py`?

If so, what disadvantages would this bring?

I guess a major advantage would be a reduction of time spent importing even though its only a couple of seconds saved...

Comment: No, it doesn't save time: All imported modules are cached. Importing something another module already imported reuses the copy from the cache, and so effectively takes no time at all.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: If you had dozens or hundreds of places where you needed to import `imp_mod` it could save some time; the code that handles imports does cache, but it does a surprising amount of work before the cache is checked, so reducing 10 * #modules - 1 cached imports to #modules - 1 cached imports might save a tiny bit on start up time. No affect on runtime unless you have functions that are importing internally to reduce startup time in exchange for cached module lookup overhead.

Comment: That said, the costs are still pretty trivial; directly looking up a module known to be in the cache, e.g. `sys.modules['collections']` takes (on my machine) ~60 ns, while `import collections` performed repeatedly takes ~350 ns each use. Saving one three-thousandth of a second per import is not that impressive. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it would allow you to access them. If you place these imports in `imp_mod.py`:

```
from os import listdir
from collections import defaultdict
from copy import deepcopy
```

Then, you could do this in another file, say, `myfile.py`:

```
import imp_mod
imp_mod.listdir
imp_mod.defaultdict
imp_mod.deepcopy
```

You're wrong about reduction of importing time, as what happens is the opposite. Python will need to import `imp_mod` and then import the other modules afterwards, while the first import would not be needed if you were importing these modules in `myfile.py` itself. If you do the same imports in another file, they will already be in cache, so virtually no time is spent in the next import.

The real disadvantage here is less readability. Whoever looks at `imp_mod.listdir`, for example, will ask himself what the heck is this method and why it has the same name as that `os` module's method. When he had to open `imp_mod.py` just to find out that it's the same method, well, he probably wouldn't be happy. I wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

As lucasnadalutti mentioned, you can access them by importing your module.

In terms of advantages, it can make your main program care less about where the imports are coming from if the `imp_mod` handles all imports, however, as your program gets more complex and starts to include more namespaces, this approach can get more messy. You can start to handle a bit of this by using `__init__.py` within directories to handle imports to do a similar thing, but as things get more complex, personally, I feel it add a little more complexity. I'd rather just know where a module came from to look it up.